# RewriteRule won't match if trailing slash present, throws nginx 404

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

With this `.htaccess`...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^foo$ foo.php
RewriteRule ^foo/$ foo.php
```

...I get the following behavior, when I request

- `/foo` — works, I get foo.php
- `/foo/` — fails unexpectedly with a bare 404 from nginx
- `/foobar` — fails, as expected, but with a pretty 404 ErrorDoc from nginx

Note: there is no folder `foo` present.

Am I missing something or is this the hosting provider's fault, like a nginx proxy misconfiguration? On a different apache, this setup works as expected.
(I'm trying to drill down why WordPress's (default-ish) .htaccess doesn't work.)

Comment: If you are getting a 404 response from an Nginx server then this evidently has nothing to do with your `.htaccess` file (which obviously only applies to Apache). Are you sure you're using Apache at all?!

Comment: @MrWhite looks like you're right... two "websites" in the same account run on apache and nginx, apparently. I just assumed it was a nginx (reverse?) proxy in front of apache because mod_rewrite *half* works...

Comment: Yes, I too would have assumed an Nginx proxy in front of Apache if it wasn't for your last example... "`/foobar` — fails, as expected, but with a pretty 404 ErrorDoc from nginx". But then again, if mod_rewrite "half works" then maybe this is just a proxy. I assume then that `foo.php` is served from Apache? If you remove `.htaccess` altogether and request `/foo`, is `/foo.php` still served? (This is could indicate that MultiViews is enabled in the server config, so `.htaccess` may not be doing what you think it's doing?)

Comment: @MrWhite without `.htaccess` `/foo.php` is not served. Thank you for your input, I've contacted support now, because this looks more and more like misconfiguration on their part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E-mailed support, they fixed it.
From what phpinfo tells me, `$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']` changed from `nginx` to `Apache`...
For future searches: this was on the web host provider checkdomain.de.